# Difference between global variable, constant, define variable, static variable, and Non static Variable in Php

Tags: php, variables

I was asked this question in an interview please can some reply on this:
what is the Difference between all these types of variable in Php global variable, constant, define(defines a constant), static variable, and Nonstatic Variable.

Comment: The official docs can help: [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php). And there is no such thing as "define variable" in PHP. `define` defines a constant.

Comment: Please refer [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score -1):

Global variables refer to any variable that is defined outside of the function.

Global variables can be accessed from any part of the script i.e. inside and outside of the function. So, a global variable can be declared just like other variable but it must be declared outside of function definition

Constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. The value cannot be changed during the script. A constant is case-sensitive by default. By convention, constant identifiers are always uppercase. No '$' sign used for declare constant.

```
const PI=3.14;

define('PI',3.14);

const cannot be used to conditionally define constants. To define a global constant, it has to be used in the outermost scope:
`
if (...) {
    const FOO = 'BAR';    // Invalid
}
// but
if (...) {
    define('FOO', 'BAR'); // Valid
}
`
```

The fundamental difference between those two ways is that constant defines constants at compile time, whereas **define** defines them at run time.

Static: Normally, when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be deleted. We need it for a further job.For that purpose we use static keyword.

Non Static: When a function is completed/executed, all of its variables are deleted.And, initialized again.